# Request method 'POST' not supported. Spring+Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Hi everyone. I ran into a problem while developing a web application. The saveEmployee method does not work properly and throws the corresponding error. In the project I use Spring-boot + Thymeleaf. I think there is an error in these two files or a problem in the configuration. But so far I haven't found anything.
**

****myRestController.java****

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/shop")
public class myRestController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;


    @GetMapping("/allEmployees")
    public String allEmployees(Model model) {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
        model.addAttribute("employeesList", employees);
        return "allEmployees";
    }

    @GetMapping("/allEmployees/{name}")
    public String getEmployeeByName(@PathVariable String name, Model model) {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.findAllByName(name);
        model.addAttribute("employeesList", employees);
        return "allEmployees";
    }

    @GetMapping("/newEmployee")
    public String addEmployee(Model model) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "addNewEmployee";
    }

    @RequestMapping()
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee){
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return "index";
    }
```

****addNewEmployee.html****

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add Employee</h1>

<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{shop/allEmployees}" th:object="${employee}">
    <label for="name">Enter name:</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="surname">Enter surname:</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}" id="surname"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="department">Enter department:</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{department}" id="department"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="salary">Enter salary:</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{salary}" id="salary"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create!">
</form>

<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `myRestController.java`, I am not seeing any `@PostMapping` defined.  In `addNewEmployee.html`, it appears you are attempting to call shop/allEmployees with a `POST` rather than the `GET` method.  If your intention is to pass a body or form to the `shop/allEmployees` endpoint, you may want to consider either changing your `@GetMapping` to a `@PostMapping` that accepts a `@RequestBody` or creating an entirely new `@PostMapping` that accepts a `@RequestBody`.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the annotations need to be changed. The idea was this: create an empty employee in the addEmployee method, place it in the model and pass it to addEmployee.html. In addEmployee.html, we populate the employee object with data and call the saveEmployee method, which puts the employee into the database and returns us to the index.html page.

Comment: Because in your form you have `th:method="POST" th:action="@{shop/allEmployees}"` which translates to sending a POST reguest to `/allEmployees`.   Since you've annotated your controller with `@GetMapping("/allEmployees")` there is no POST method defined.